# Transpose and copy to row to column

Tags: excel-2007

I have a row of data in say A1:AA1 in worksheet A. In worksheet B I have a range for data from A1:A25. I need the data from the row in worksheet A to be transposed into the data range in worksheet B. I can Paste Special and paste in the values but I need the information in worksheet A to update automatically that in worksheet B.

Comment: Did you try =Transpose(A1:B10) with CTRL+SHFT+ENter

Answer (score 0):

Select A1:A25 in Sheet B and enter:

```
=TRANSPOSE(A!A1:AA1)
```

with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

However won't fit 27 columns into 25 rows.